# Crop image in Fluid Template with image viewhelper

Tags: typo3, fluid

I want to crop images in Fluid with the `f:image` or the `f:uri.image` viewhelper (TYPO3 8.7). Since TYPO3 7.2 the usual way does not work anymore:

This:

```
<f:image image="{file}" width="500c" height="500" />
```

does not work.

In the fluid guide I found the hint that since TYPO3 7.2 I have to use crop. I found this in the change log: 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/7.6/Changelog/7.2/Feature-65584-AddImageCropping.html

So this should work, but it doesnt:

```
<f:image image="{file}" crop="0,0,500,500" />
```

The images are rendered but in default size.

Any ideas? Anything changed in later versions?

Comment: Is normal resizing of images working? As the first example seems to be correct.

Comment: yes. <f:image image="{file}" maxWidth="500" /> works as expected.

Comment: And the image is bigger than 500x500?

Comment: yes, 1600 x 1200.

Comment: all manipulations work except in combination with m or c or with crop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried with a fresh installation and found my fault.

1. cropping with c and m does indeed work in TYPO3 8 - the hint in the fluid manual is wrong.
2. in short syntax you have to use '' in order to send the c or m correct.

This syntax is wrong:

```
 <img src="{f:uri.image(image:file, width:200c, height:200)}">
```

there is no error message and the images are rendered but the letter c is ignored. You have to use this syntax:

```
<img src="{f:uri.image(image:file, width:'200c', height:'200')}">
```

this will work.

One additional hint: after changing the syntax the images are not rendered every time but only when the size has changed. Sometimes you get simply the cached images ... Deleting the content on /fileadmin/_temp does help.

Well - perhaps it will help some one :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `f:image` like below. it's work for me.

```
<f:image src="{file.originalResource.publicUrl}" width="770c" height="517c" height="350c" />
```

Comment: Why did you specify the height twice?

Answer (score 0):

You could also specify the crop settings in tca and use this settings in the FE, for an example look at the repository : https://github.com/frans-beech-it/t3ext-config_examples.

Besides that, in the install tool you can check if cropping works on your machine. It can happen that there are already processed images for your size, if you adjust the cropping information of image with 1px a new processed image is created. If then the image works, clear the processed files to generate a new image for your desired formats.